# Combine many Kotlin flows to get just their current value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I'm using the Preference APIs that return flows.
There are cases when I need to combine values from different preferences. I know I can use
`flow.combine`.

Since the method where I need to combine is a `suspend` function and the value from the flows do not need to flow anywhere anymore, I could also define something like this:

```
suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.currentValue(): T {
    var res: T? = null
    this.collect {
        res = it
    }
    return res!!
}
```

and then just read one value at at time:

```
    val val1 = flow1.currentValue()
    val val2 = flow2.currentValue()
    val val3 = flow3.currentValue()
```

Is there a better way to do it? Or should I just use the `combine` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define a `currentValue` function. There is already a `Flow.first()` function that returns the first value of the Flow. Since these Flows are designed to always emit an initial value with the current value of the preference, this will work fine.

Side note, your `currentValue()` function will never return because `collect` doesn't return until the Flow is complete.

Whether you want to individually call `first()` on each Flow or `combine` all of them and call `first()` on the combined Flow is up to you. I don't think it's any cleaner either way.